# How to correct the layout to have the button displayed?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wizard6_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/wizard6_title"
            android:textColor="#0088cc"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wizard6_text1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:text="@string/wizard6_text1"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/wizard6_btn_file"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/wizard6_btn_file" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/wizard6_btn_back"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/wizard_back" />
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/wizard6_btn_next"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/wizard_next" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

`wizard6_text1` text there is scrollable (`mTextView5.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())`), but on the small screens it takes the remaining space and `wizard6_btn_file` is not displayed in result. How should I fix it?

Comment: Did you tried <activity android:name=".DocEdit" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"> for your activity in manifest?

Comment: @Sigrlami, just tried - it doesn't help.

Comment: could you post couple of screenshots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have that kind of trouble its probably because you haven't set the layout weights. Android by default uses 0, which means take all the needed space. Try adding to your textview with a lot of text:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Hope it helps!